# How to resolve data type serialization error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am consuming a webservice which returns a dataset. There is a a row item in one of the datatables which is of type Microsoft.Sqlserver.Types.Sqlgeometry.

The exception is thrown when deserialization occurs and I cannot find a solution which is not too much of a hack. I imagine it could be because this dll does not exist on my machine.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is due to that type? What is the whole error? Is it possible for you to obtain the dll by installing a client-side of SQLServer and test again?

Comment: What kind of exception?  Any inner exceptions with more details?

Comment: It seems the error is related to that type specifically , since another method which does not return that type from the same service works fine. @BerndLinde

Comment: I dig your LiquidSnake